# Ruby - "can't convert Symbol into Integer" when try to access data in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, integer, symbols

Here's a sample of array:

```
{"C1"=>[
        {:upc=>"51857195821952", :product_id=>"1234", :name=>"name", :price=>" $15 ", :color=>"green", :size=>"L", :description=>"descr"},
        {:upc=>"352353wegs", :product_id=>"456", :name=>"name2", :price=>"$21", :color=>"black", :size=>"S", :description=>"descr"}, # ...
       ],
 #...
}
```

And here as I am trying to fetch data from that array:

```
@array.each do |p|
  product = Product.new
  product.sku = p[0]
  product.name = p[1][0][:name] #can't convert Symbol into Integer
  price = p[1].select{ |pr| !pr[:price].nil? and pr[:price] != "0" }.min_by{ |i| i[:price].to_f }[:price]
  product.price = "%.2f" % (price.to_f)
  ...
end
```

Every time I try to fetch data from the array, I get on the line `product.name =` the error **can't convert Symbol into Integer**.

What is wrong in this case? I spent a part of afternoon on this issue, but unfortunately I still cannot figure out it...

Thanky you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `@array` is actually a hash. It is formated like following:

```
{ 
  'name1' => [{:upc => "..."},{:upc => "..."}],
  'name2' => [{:upc => "..."},{:upc => "..."}],
  #...
}
```

Since it is a Hash, you can use 2 arguments in the `each` (works for `map` also) method (one for the key, the other for the value):

```
@array.each do |name, array|
  product = Product.new
  product.sku = name # returns "C1"
  array.each do |data|
    data[:upc]
    data[:name]
    #etc...
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you. But how can I access the price element? The current way how I am trying to obtain that generate error `private method 'select' called for "\"":String`

Comment: You can access to it using `data[:price]` but this will return a string like " 15$ ", you have to `strip` it and `gsub` the '$' before converting it into a Float

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the *sample array* you showed above is **not** actually an array. It's a hash with key-value pairs. Therefore, your code like `p[0]` or `p[1][0]` doesn't make sense because a hash doesn't have `index` like array. Hash is not ordered. Hashes values are accessed with a "key" rather than an "index" like array.

Iterating through key-value pairs of a hash is done something like this.

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > x = {:x => 10, :y => 9, :z => 10}
 => {:x=>10, :y=>9, :z=>10} 
1.9.3p194 :002 > x.each do |key, value|
1.9.3p194 :003 >   puts "#{key} : #{value}"
1.9.3p194 :004?> end 
x : 10
y : 9
z : 10
 => {:x=>10, :y=>9, :z=>10}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be confusing Arrays and Hashes a bit.

Given this:

```
@array = {"C1"=>[
  {:upc=>"51857195821952", :product_id=>"1234", :name=>"name", :price=>" $15 ", :color=>"green", :size=>"L", :description=>"descr"}, 
  {:upc=>"352353wegs", :product_id=>"456", :name=>"name2", :price=>" $21 ", :color=>"black", :size=>"S", :description=>"descr"} 
] }
```

Then `@array.class.name` is `Hash`

You can get the actual array by accessing it like so:

```
@actual_array = @array["C1"]
```

Then, `@actual_array.class.name` will be `Array`

So, taking this approach and re-writing:

```
@array = {"C1"=>[
  {:upc=>"51857195821952", :product_id=>"1234", :name=>"name", :price=>" $15 ", :color=>"green", :size=>"L", :description=>"descr"}, 
  {:upc=>"352353wegs", :product_id=>"456", :name=>"name2", :price=>" $21 ", :color=>"black", :size=>"S", :description=>"descr"} 
 ] }

@actual_array = @array["C1"]

@actual_array.each do |p|
  puts p[:name]
end
```

If you do this, you'll find that the value of the `:name` element will be printed neatly out.